# What to do when nothing comes on screen after debugging but as soon as I reload it the layout appears

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using listview under which there are 4 things:
Text 
Drop-down
Graph
Listview...The last three are bringing data from API

Comment: please share some code to better explain your problem.

Comment: There is an error of perform layout

Comment: Please post a minimal reproduction. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve